# How to use gunicorn django and procfile with nested dirs?

Tags: python, django, heroku, procfile

The project structure goes like

```
back\
 |anwis\
 | |anwis\
 | |...
 | |wsgi.py
 |dg.sqlite3
 |manage.py
 |...
 |venv\
 | |...
 |Procfile
 |...
```

In that Procfile i tried various things like

```
web: gunicorn anwis.wsgi
```

or

```
web: gunicorn anwis.anwis.wsgi
```

But somehow it all ended up now working, it just says
`"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anwis.wsgi'"` and that's it, there's nothing left to do else, i figure out that it needs a relative path to the wsgi file, but what is it then?